# Function to create Highcharts where the series has the correct prototype

Tags: highcharts

I am attempting to write a function to add a highchart to a page and a function that can update the data for that chart based on a streaming API. I added a setInterval to simulate the streaming api.

The issue occurs on line 80. I believe it is because I have not set the series array with the chart object properly. When I need to add new data via 'addPoint', the prototype is not there. What am I missing in my AddChart function that wires the series up to highcharts?

FIDDLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/puto3Lg0/2/

```
$(function () {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var metrics = [];

        Highcharts.setOptions({
            global: {
                useUTC: false
            }
        });

        function AddChart(metric) {
            $("#divMain").append('<div id="' + metric.key + '" style="min-width: 310px; height: 200px; margin: 0 auto"></div>');
            $('#' + metric.key).highcharts({
                chart: {
                    type: 'spline',
                    animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
                    marginRight: 10,

                },
                title: {
                    text: metric.Title
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime',
                    tickPixelInterval: 150
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Messages'
                    },
                    plotLines: [
                        {
                            value: 0,
                            width: 1,
                            color: '#808080'
                        }
                    ]
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                            Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>' +
                            Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                exporting: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                series: metric.series
        });
        };



        function ParseData(message) {

            var jsonObj = JSON.parse(message);

            $.each(jsonObj.Metrics, function(index, value) {
                var metricName = value.Metric.Name.replace(' ', '');
                if (metrics[metricName] == undefined) {

                    metrics[metricName] = {
                        "title": value.Metric.Name,
                        "key": metricName,
                        "series": [
                            {
                                name: value.Metric.Name,
                                data: []
                            }
                        ],
                    }

                    AddChart(metrics[metricName]);
                }

                metrics[metricName].series.addPoint([new Date().getTime(), parseInt(value.Metric.CurrentValue)], true, false);
            });
        };

        setInterval(function () {

            var m = "{\"Metrics\": [{\"Metric\":{\"Name\":\"Queue 01\",\"CurrentValue\":\"0\",\"TimeStamp\":\"\\\x2FDate(1415826323291)\\\x2F\"}},{\"Metric\":{\"Name\":\"Queue 02\",\"CurrentValue\":\"3\",\"TimeStamp\":\"\\\x2FDate(1415826323344)\\\x2F\"}},{\"Metric\":{\"Name\":\"Queue 03\",\"CurrentValue\":\"9\",\"TimeStamp\":\"\\\x2FDate(1415826323405)\\\x2F\"}}]}";

            ParseData(m);
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have `metrics` declared as an array.  Should be an empty object:

```
var metrics = {};
```

Second, the data structure you've created, `metrics[metricName].series` is not a Highcharts series object.  It's an object you created and used to supply Highcharts data.  To get the real series object, you'll have to get it back from the chart.

```
 // getting the chart from the DOM, then the first series...
 $("#"+metricName).highcharts().series[0].addPoint([new Date().getTime(), parseInt(value.Metric.CurrentValue)], true, false);
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/puto3Lg0/4/).